# Setting onclick listener on imageView in listview using Custom Adapter

Tags: android

I have two activities MainActivity.java and Second.java. I want that when the user clicks on image view its background image will change and when user clicks on any item in list, Second `Activity` will open.
Here is My code, it's not working.....

rowlaout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="22dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ok" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="30sp" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

dataListAdapter.java

```
class dataListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        String[] Title;
        Context context;
        ImageView i1;
        TextView t1;
        public dataListAdapter(Context cont,String[] text) {
            Title = text;
            context=cont;
        }
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return Title.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);;
            View row;
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
            i1=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.button);
            t1=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.label);
            t1.setText(Title[position]);
            i1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                i1.setImageResource(R.drawable.no); 
                }
            });
            return (row);
        }
```

}

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Intent intent;
    ListView list;
    int [] state;
    int po;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
         String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
                    "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
                    "Linux", "OS/2" };
         dataListAdapter adapter = new dataListAdapter(this, values);
         list.setAdapter(adapter);
         list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

             @Override
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                  int position, long id) { 

             String  itemValue= (String) list.getItemAtPosition(position);
             Bundle sendBundle = new Bundle();
             sendBundle.putString("value", itemValue);
             intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Second.class);
             intent.putExtras(sendBundle);
             startActivity(intent);
             po=position;
            }
         });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

First you should change visibility of ImageView i1 i.e. it should not be visible out of getView method.

```
    Context context;
    // ImageView i1; // remove this declaration from here
    TextView t1;

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);;
        View row;
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
      final ImageView i1=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.button);
        t1=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.label);
        t1.setText(Title[position]);
        i1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            i1.setImageResource(R.drawable.no); 

            // OR
            // ((ImageView)view).setImageResource(R.drawable.no); 
            }
        });
        return (row);
    }
```

after this try to set imageResource using handler in onClick() method

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      new Handler().post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            i1.setImageResource(R.drawable.no); 
        }
    });
 }
```

This should resolve your issue.